# Java bubble sort help needed

Tags: java, bubble-sort

Good evening,

My and my bud tried to figure out why the program won't bubble sort the names that we input, maybe someone could hint about it.

```
 public static void sortDatPlane(String Ref[]){


    int n = Ref.length;
    int k = 1;
    int j = n - 2;
    int i;

    while(k < n){
        i = 0;
        while (i <= j) {
            if(notInOrder(Ref, i, i+1)){
                swap(Ref, i, i+1);
            }
            i++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    for (String Ref1 : Ref) {
        System.out.println(Ref1);
    }

}

public static void swap(String Ref[], int i, int j){
        String temp = Ref[i];
        Ref[i] = Ref[j];
        Ref[j] = temp;
}

public static boolean notInOrder(String Ref[],int i, int j){
    return Ref[i].substring(0,1).compareTo(Ref[j].substring(0,1)) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what swap and notInOrder do

Comment: And describe what goes wrong. What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: @Bálint edited, sorry. It won't sort, just prints as a regular listing (#1 - aac #2 - aab - #3 aaa)

Comment: Why are you only comparing the first character of the strings? And `compareTo()` doesn't guarantee that only `1` means `greater than` - it can be any positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by  Ken Y-N in the comments, you are only comparing the first characters of the strings (`substring(0, 1)` does this). Remove that part and it will probably work.

Comment: It already works: OP's output is perfectly sorted by the first character (;->)

Comment: @Kevin That sounds like a feature to me